# MS Access SQL: Use a field value to determine proper field to use in calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic, lookup

I apologize I struggled in writing the title to accurately express what I am trying to do. I hope I can explain it well in the body of this text, I will simplify my problem as much as possible.

I have a table with 5 fields,

`ID, Base Period, Period 1, Period 2, Period 3`

The `Base Period` field will say either `Period 1` or `Period 2`, what I need to do is write a query that will either do `Period 2 / Period 1` if `Base Period = 'Period 1'` OR do `Period 3 / Period 2` if `Base Period = 'Period 2'`

I know I can do: `IIF([Base Period] = 'Period 1',Period 2 / Period 1,IIF....)` however, I have many, many, periods of information - Imagine each period as a month or day.

Essentually, I just want the value in `Base Period` to inform the query to take the value from the field that is named within `Base Period`.

I am OK splitting the table if it is easier (and I vaguely remember accomplishing a similar task doing something like this, I just can't seem to find where it is!)

Comment: Your table design is bad; it needs to be normalized.  That's why you're having this problem.  Failing that, the IIF is probably the only reasonable solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey table design is not always the solution

Comment: @Yuck: It is here.  This is a straightforward normalization problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split your table so that each ID + Period combination is one record.

```
ID                  Primary Key
ParentID            Foreign Key
PeriodID            Identifies the period
Value               The value of the Period for the given parent.
```